# Как вывести список всех переменных из другого файла (кода)?

Tags: python, variable

Например есть файл кода (text.py):

```
a = 5
b = 'hello'
c = True 
def d (): 
      f = 4
class x ():
       l = 4
```

Нужно открыть файл в другом коде и получить список всех переменных без аргументов

Вывод должен выглядеть так:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'l']
```

Пробовал сделать так:

```
example = open ('text.py')
members = [attr for attr in dir(example) if not callable(getattr(example, attr)) and not attr.startswith("__")]
print (members)
```

Comment: `import text; print(dir(text)) #  'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x'`, но естественно без внутренних переменных; dir(text.x) добавит l . Но внутреннюю переменную функции так не увидеть, она еще даже не создана

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если как в вашем варианте, то можно регулярками найти просто все присваивания:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'\s*(\w+)\s*=')
result = set()
with open('text.py') as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.match(pattern, line)
        if m:
            result.add(m[1])
print(result)
# {'b', 'a', 'c', 'l', 'f'}
```

Но, конечно, случаи могут быть сложнее и тогда такой вариант уже не прокатит.

Множество использовано на случай повторных присваиваний в ту же переменную.

Comment: Спасибо за решение! Если будут сложные варианты кода, то буду отталкиваться от вашего способа